# How to access nested input attribute using Jsoup

Tags: input, nested, jsoup, attr

Please could You help my with selecting int value from input attr"value"? In this case "12".

```
<td class="fit-content">
<div class="add-cart" data-original-title="Ilość w op. zbiorczym: 12 szt.">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" value="12">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
String value = doc.selectFirst("div.add-cart div.input-group input").attr("value");
```